# How to show url of the site that redirects toward my ec2 adress instead of the static ec2 adress ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a web site that makes a redirection towards an ec2 instance.
I have the file /etc/nginx/conf.d/react.conf configured like so:

```
  server {
  listen 80;
  server_name domainName.com www.domainName.com;
  index index.html; 
  listen [::]:80;
  root /var/www/html/myApp;
    #react app
  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;  
  }
}
```

The problem i have is that after the website makes a redirection towards my ec2 instance, the url that is shown becomes the static ip adress of my ec2 instance, instead of showing the url of the website that makes the redirection. How to solve this?

Comment: I think the website is not hosted on the EC2, is it? So I think you should redirect to a recorded DNS domain not the public IP. if I'm getting your requirements wrong please provide some more details